# Is there a way to trick or force a consumer graphics card to use workstation card drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, display-driver, nvidia-quadro

Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/690388/why-do-workstation-graphics-cards-cost-far-more-than-equivalent-consumer-graphic) and [the chosen answer](https://superuser.com/a/690401/24461), in particular this bit:

> There are some minor differences to create this rate fence - for example, the Quadro / Fire Pro models use different drivers which prioritize rendering accuracy over speed.

Which to me means (with exception of some cards which use different hardware such as ECC memory), in theory, that I could install those same workstation drivers on my cheaper consumer card and do "stable" 3D/Fractal/OpenGL/etc. rendering.

My question:

Is it possible to install workstation drivers (for e.g. Quadro/Fire Pro) on a consumer graphics card, considering that it uses the same GPU?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible on some GeForce cards. You have to [program them to report as Quadros](http://www.techarp.com/showarticle.aspx?artno=539&pgno=1) and you'll be able to install Quadro drivers. But it won't make the card exactly identical to Quadro. The latter ones usually have more memory and slightly different hardware design. Still, modding a GeForce will unlock some of its potential which is supported by hardware, but locked by NVIDIA to prevent you from using features you haven't paid for. Of course you're doing all modding on your own responsibility and it will void your warranty.

Comment: [By law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act), it won't void your warranty in the United States unless the manufacturer can prove that your modifications caused the problem. Otherwise, car manufacturers could void your warranty if you changed your own oil.